# Firebug like tool for Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firebug

Is there a tool like firebug for Chrome? - it should be able to show the content as well as the code simultaneously in one screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or press `Ctrl-Shift-I` (this shows the content as well as the code on the one screen)

Comment: Is there a way to select elements from the screen by clicking on them - the way we can with Firebug?

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-I, then 'Elements' tab, then press magnifying glass icon bottom of screen - same as Firebug from there

Answer (score 2):

What about [Firebug Lite for Google Chrome?](http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/)

Answer (score 2):

Chrome comes with [developer tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/) built in (Menu -> Tools -> Developer Tools).